# Managing a Faux Tree in C#

Tags: c#, tree

I have been tasked with adding a feature to an existing code base. The code was primarily written by a developer that just left our team. With that in mind, I have some limitations :/.

The developer had previously written some code that looks something of a cross between a List and Tree. In the user interface, its a tree structure. However, in code, its a List. Its a little odd. The two main classes are defined here:

```
public class TreeBranch
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

public class TreeItem
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public Guid TreeBranchID { get; set; }
  public Guid? ParentTreeItemID { get; set; }

  public int Level { get; set; }

  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime? MarkedOn { get; set; }
}
```

So, TreeBranch is stored in a database table and TreeItem is stored in a database table. A query is performed that returns all of the TreeItem elements with a specific TreeBranchID whose MarkedOn value is NULL. That is handled list this:

```
List<TreeItem> treeItems = GetTreeBranchItems("someID");
treeItems.Sory(new TreeItemComparer());
```

My TreeItemComparer class looks like the following:

```
public class TreeItemComparer: IComparer<TreeItem>
{
  // allow us to look up parent Items by GUID
  IDictionary<Guid, TreeItem> itemLookup;

  public TreeItemComparer(IEnumerable<TreeItem> list)
  {
    itemLookup = list.ToDictionary(item => item.ID);
    foreach (var item in list)
      SetLevel(item);
  }

  public int SetLevel(TreeItem item)
  {
    if ((item.Level == 0) && (item.ParentTreeItemID != Guid.Empty))
    {
      if (itemLookup.ContainsKey(item.ParentTreeItemID))
        item.Level = 1 + SetLevel(itemLookup[item.ParentTreeItemID]);
    }
    else if (item.ParentTreeItemID == Guid.Empty)
      item.Level = 1;

    return item.Level;
  }

  public int Compare(TreeItem x, TreeItem y)
  {
    // see if x is a child of y
    while (x.Level > y.Level)
    {
      if ((x.ParentTreeItemID == y.ID) || (x.ParentTreeItemID == Guid.Empty))
        return 1;
      x = itemLookup[x.ParentTreeItemID];
    }

    // see if y is a child of x
    while (y.Level > x.Level)
    {
      if ((y.ParentTreeItemID == x.ID) || (y.ParentTreeItemID == Guid.Empty))
        return -1;
    }

    // x and y are not parent-child, so find common ancestor
    while (x.ParentTreeItemID != y.ParentTreeItemID)
    {
      if (x.ParentTreeItemID != Guid.Empty)
        x = itemLookup[x.ParentTreeItemID];
      if (y.ParentTreeItemID != Guid.Empty)
        y = itemLookup[y.ParentTreeItemID];
    }

    // compare createDate of children of common ancestor
    return x.CreatedOn.CompareTo(y.CreatedOn);
  }
}
```

This code works, with one exception. Occasionally, I'll get a broken tree. For instance, if I have a structure that looks like the following:

```
Item 1
  Item 1-A  (Imagine this TreeItem has a MarkedOn value that is NOT null)
    Item 1-A-a
      Item 1-A-a-1
    Item 1-A-b
  Item 1-B
```

Well, in the example above, I should only really have the following:

```
Item 1
  Item 1-B
```

However, I'm getting

```
Item 1
  Item 1-A-a
    Item 1-A-a-1
  Item 1-A-b
  Item 1-B
```

My problem is, the TreeItem with a MarkedOn value and ALL OF ITS "children" should NOT be part of the collection. Because of our environment, I can't touch the database :(. At the same time, I'm not sure how to do this in code. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any logic reliant on MarkedOn. Since you said that particular bit of code is what is breaking, it would help to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter your results after you get them back from the database.

```
List<TreeItem> orphanedItems = new List<TreeItem>();
foreach (TreeItem item in results)
{
    if (item.ParentTreeItemID != Guid.Empty &&
        !results.Any(tree => tree.ID == item.ParentTreeItemID)
    {
        orphanedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
foreach (TreeItem orphan in orphanedItems)
    results.Remove(orphan);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the line "!results.Contains(tree -> tree.ID == item.ParentTreeItemID)". I get a compile time error. I thought you may be trying the lambda operator in place of "->" however, I got a compile time error with that too.

Comment: @EelsFan: To much F# programming, I will fix it.